# How to use an Observable in Input Angular Decorator?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a doubt about Subject. I'm using an Observable in parent component and I'm passing it to child component through the decorator Input.

In child component, I get that stream and apply a `next()` for the parent component receives the data which is coming from child component.

Child Component:

```
@Input() test = new Subject<any>();

private sendDataToParent(data:any): void {
this.test.next(data);
}
```

Parent Component:

```
test = new Subject<any>();

ngOnInit() {

this.test.subscribe(console.log)

}
```

In that case, I'm using an Input Decorator as Outuput Decorator. There is a better way to connect to component through an Subject?

That way I applied Which problems I can find with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular is built to pass data to children components via properties (input) and send back to parents with events (output).

In your scenario I can't see nay reason to not pass data to the parent in an `@Output` property:

```
@Output() test = new EventEmitter<any>();
private sendDataToParent(data:any): void {
    this.test.emit(data);
}

<app-child (test)="parentMethod($event)></app-child>
```

If you need to expand your knowledge about this topic you should read this documentation:
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Anyway, sometimes you need the same data across multiple components, multiple parents or children, and you can use `Observables` to manage this, but you should create a service to be injected in all that components.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyDataService {
    private dataSubject$: BehaviorSubject<MyData> = new BehaviorSubject<MyData>(null);

    getData$(): Observable<MyData> {
        return this.dataSubject$;
    }

    changeData(data: MyData) {
        this.dataSubject$.next(data);
    }
}
```

And your components can subscribe to that service:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    public data$: Observable<MyData>;

    constructor(private dataService: MyDataService) {
        this.data$ = this.dataService.getData$();
    }

    ngOnInit() {}

    changeData(data: MyData) {
        this.dataService.changeData(data);
    }
}
```

You can use `data$` in your html with `async` pipe, or if you prefer you can subscribe manually in code, but don't forget to unsubscribe inside `ngOnDestroy`, this could be a way to do it:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private destroy$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    constructor(private dataService: MyDataService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService.getData$()
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.detroy$))
            .subscribe(data => {
                // do x
            });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.destroy$.next(true);
        this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
    }

    changeData(data: MyData) {
        this.dataService.changeData(data);
    }
}
```